# Actionscript 3.0 Is there a way to simply target all objects that belong to a class and run a function-method from that class from eg. main timeline?

Tags: actionscript-3

[image]
I'm still total AS3 noob so.. have mercy.. but want to become a lot better in near future!

Maybe it's a stupid question or there is other simple way (like running it form inside a class), but I couldn't find it and I'm interested in running it form main timeline. I will be glad if someone can help me :)

btw..

i want to run function-method called mov_to_right(); for all boxes(object with "box" class) form main timeline

my "box" class code..

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class box extends MovieClip {


    public function box() {

        function mov_to_right(){
            x+=80;
        }
    }

}
```

}

and the error message: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1    1061: Call to a possibly undefined method mov_to_right through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: In short, NO. In long, you can do a collection of those boxes at creation time (or at runtime via tricks) into an array, and use `Array.foreach()` against that array.

Comment: THANK YOU! I knew something about array, but still wondered if it can be done in other ways. I'm new to AS (and programming in general) and have a lot of connection with programs like scirra Construct (there was that possibility)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move all children inside Box Class:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i< this.numChildren; i++)
{
    if(this.getChildAt(i) is MovieClip)
    {
        (this.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip).x += 80;
    }
}
```

But if you have a class with many Box classes as children and just want to move them:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i< this.numChildren; i++)
{
    if(this.getChildAt(i) is Box)
    {
        (this.getChildAt(i) as Box).x += 80;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to get more into arrays and loops to see what it can do!